# unauthorized error when posting user credentials in the request body

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I can login into my spring boot application when i sent a post request with user credentials in the link to

http://localhost:8088/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user&password=password

I receive a token. However, I get the error "unauthorized" when i try to postthe credentials in the body as x-www-form-urlencoded to http://localhost:8088/oauth/token

this is my authorization server configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends 
AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)     throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        endpoints.tokenStore(getTokenStore());
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore getTokenStore(){
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws     Exception {
        clients.inMemory().
                withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT","ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT").scopes("read","write","trust")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource").accessTokenValiditySeconds(5000).secret("secret");
    }


    @Override
   public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
   }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Thank you for the comment but I am trying to do the opposite of that. The guy's instructions i followed has both authentication options working(1. post request with credentials in the link 2. post request with credentials in body). in my case, option 2 is not working. sorry if my post was confusing

Comment: I understand your problem. check this out : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/804

Comment: Thank you again! that link is addressing exactly my problem. But it is really bugging me that in the tutorial I used both methods work fine this is the [github repo](https://github.com/arocketman/SpringBlog) for the project. The only different thing at my end in that I am using Mongodb instead of H2db